# My ssh root access disabled. how can i get it back?

Tags: centos, ssh, vps

i'm very noobs in server. 
I've VPS running centos 7. everything goes normal until i make a mistake.
I want to create a new SSH user to access my VPS. i surf on internet to find the solution and find some setup in sshd_config like this

```
Port 1234
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers jim
```

then i save it and restart the server. but now i can access my ssh both with user "jim" or root. and now i can't edit that config cause can't login to ssh. does anyone can help me please

Thanks

Comment: boot your rescue console and correct your config file.

Comment: And this is why you don't follow some internet tutorials if you don't understand what they do...

Comment: Tip for next time: When editing the SSH configuration, always test it first before restarting sshd (whole server not necessary). The best test is to leave your client CLI terminal open, start a new one and try to log in through a new session. If it doesn't work as intended, at least you still have your original session open.

Answer (score 1):

login with different account and su - root and change configuration in sshd_config ,
change permitRootlogin yes

restart the service

check  with another session.

Comment: the problem is i not set user "jim" password yet